# Javascript no lee funciones, o no funciona si no se pone return false

Tags: javascript, jquery

Se supone que mi función debería tranquilamente reemplazar el contenido de cada elemento detectado por el each, y a su vez, buscar también la aparición de **attachment** para posteriormente realizar una función con cada attachment buscado, pero no funciona lo que va dentro del `while` si no pongo `return Cualquiercosa`, y si pongo `return`, lo que sigue después del **while**, se omite quedando como última función el `$(this).html(content)`. No se realmente lo que pasa, o que onda, es como si no leyera algunas lineas...

```js
    $(".x").each(function(){
        content = $(this).text();
        content = content.replace(/\@(.*?)\#([0-9]{5})/g, '<a class="x" x="@$1#$2">$&</a>');
        content = content.replace(/\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}/g, '<text-b>$1</text-b>');
        content = content.replace(/\-{2}(.*?)\-{2}/g, '<text-t>$1</text-t>');
        content = content.replace(/\~{2}(.*?)\~{2}/g, '<text-s>$1</text-s>');
        attachment = /\{{2}attachment:(.*?)\}{2}/g;
        attachmentsCount = (content.match(attachment) || []).length;
        while((image = attachment.exec(content))) {
        $("<img>").attr("src", "url=" + image[1]).appendTo($(this).children("x"));
        }
        var content = content.replace(attachment, '')
        $(this).html(content);
    })
```

Comment: Has inentado colocar == en vez de solo uno, en la condición del while?

Comment: @HugoQuiñónez Si querés lo intento, aunque desde mi punto de vista de principiante, creo que eso no influye la verdad en nada, porque no es como si estuviese comparando dos variables distintas, es más como forEach(var AS varible).

Comment: Me refiero a esta parte  while((image = attachment.exec(content))) estoy tratando de entender tu código, pero creo que creas un ciclo infinito... qué contiene "image" ??

Comment: "image" no contiene nada, lo puse así porque en mdn (si es que así se llamaba) explican que la condición tiene que ser una variable no usada para que luego se convierta en el array con los datos de las ocurrencias de exec, por eso es while((image = attachment.exec(content))), por cada vez que aparezca algo con el regexp del attachment, se creará el ciclo con los datos de la ocurrencia de regexp en la variable image. Es como decir while($users AS $query->fetch()) en php, y sí, lo probé como dijiste y la función deja de servir.

Comment: @HugoQuiñónez `while((image = attachment.exec(content)))` esto no necesariamente está mal porque uno puede declarar una variable dentro del while y cuando sea `undefined`, `false`, `null` ... el while acaba.  Para mi que el ciclo si es infinito pero porque el en ningun momento está cambiando `content`, lo que hace  `attachment.exec(content)` siempre devuleva algo diferente a `null ` que es lo mismo que la condicion siempre sea `true`...

Comment: @clay Tal vez sea eso, ¿Podrías ayudarme?

Comment: Yo veo dos posibles errores: para ver si es eso dentro del while escribe `console.log(content)` y mira a ver que pasa en la consola. Si te muestra muchisimas veces el mismo mensaje y no para es por eso.

Comment: Me muestra lo que hay dentro de cada string con {{attachment:xxxxxx}} dentro, pero no se genera nada infinito ni repetido, sino lo correspondiente a cada content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La condición del while al parece siempre es cierta y se queda en un bucle infinito y lo que parece es que modificas content afuera del ciclo y no adentro.

Este codigo debería funcionar

```
 $(".x").each(function(){
    content = $(this).text();
    content = content.replace(/\@(.*?)\#([0-9]{5})/g, '<a class="x" x="@$1#$2">$&</a>');
    content = content.replace(/\*{2}(.*?)\*{2}/g, '<text-b>$1</text-b>');
    content = content.replace(/\-{2}(.*?)\-{2}/g, '<text-t>$1</text-t>');
    content = content.replace(/\~{2}(.*?)\~{2}/g, '<text-s>$1</text-s>');
    attachment = /\{{2}attachment:(.*?)\}{2}/g;
    attachmentsCount = (content.match(attachment) || []).length;
    while((image = attachment.exec(content))) {
    $("<img>").attr("src", "url=" + image[1]).appendTo($(this).children("x"));
    content=content.replace(attachment, '');
    }

    $(this).html(content);
})
```

Comment: Resulta que no era nada de lo discutido arriba, lo siento todo está funcionando bien, mala mía, el elemento del DOM que especifiqué no existía JAJAJAJAJAAJAJAJ

Comment: ese era el otro posible error $("<img>") porque  creo que no va < ni > si ?